# Javascript profiler

Tags: javascript, profiling, firebug

Is there a program that will allow me to get detailed information about my script: specifically, I'd like to be able to track its memory footprint and see how many objects are in memory.  Firebug has a profiler that seems to provide timing information but I'm more interested in memory management.

Answer (score 2):

[Google Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome/intl/en/landing_chrome.html?hl=en) does this out of the box, very similar to how firebug works

Comment: Google Chrome's memory heap snapshots (which is the feature to which you refer) seem overly complicated. Additionally, very large object graphs take forever (>10 minutes before I gave up) to expand in the results. I'd like to find a better solution that what Chrome offers.

Answer (score 2):

[Google Chrome](http://google.com/chrome)/[chromium](http://chromium.org) has a built-in profiler which can not only profile CPU usage, but also take and present heap (memory) snapshots.

Comment: As mentioned in the other answer pointing to Google Chrome, the Chrome profiler is overly complicated, and performs very poorly on very large object graphs.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out this:

[JavaScript Profiler 2.0](http://www.imnmotion.com/documents/html/technical/dhtml/jsprof.html)

Answer (score 1):

I used to use a profiler called "Javascript Memory Validator" (http://www.softwareverify.com/javascript-memory.php).

This profiler was amazing. However, the last version of Firefox they supported was 3.6.6, so it looks like it's a dead product.

If you're desperate, you can install Firefox 3.6 and use this profiler.